# cannot resolve symbol in showAddDialog

Tags: java, android

I Don't Know why cannot resolve the symbol 'edit_text'
here

```
private void showAddDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
        dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);


        final EditText editTitle = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.edit_title);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just import the following.

```
import android.widget.EditText;
```

that should solve  the issue.

Or try also more imports:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
```

If it doesn't resolve the issue maybe you need to fix your .xml file

Make sure that you have assigned the id for your EditText in the .xml as below:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
 />
```